# How do I update an array that contains a dictionary with key/value pairs?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am iterating over an object that has multiple key/value pairs and I'd like to create an array of each time it iterates while updating specific values where the keys are found. I have the logic for looking for specific keys, but I'm drawing a blank on how to get an array of dictionaries.

```
data = [{'source_id': source_id,
         'order_items_code': order_items_code,
         'color': color,
         'print_sku': print_sku,
         'monogram_type': monogram_type,
         'letters': letters,
         'shadow': shadow,
         'front': front,
         'stripes': stripes
         }]
```

edit for clarification:

After iterating through the entire object, data will be appended with however many dictionaries with updated values here:
[image]

Comment: try `list(some_random_dict.items())`

Comment: what is the expected result?

Comment: Not sure what you're looking for, but `new_data = [{**d, oldkey: newval} for d in data]` might do the trick

Comment: Are you trying to convert each key/value pair into their own dictionaries?